What is difference between getSupportFragmentManager(), getChildFragmentManager(), and getParentFragmentManager?
I tried to understand but it's complex
Where can I use each of them ?
What is the scenario on the back stack for each ?
and what if I have nesteing fragments what I shuold use at this thime ?
last question Am I rghit to use this scenarios or there is some different bhavior that's instead of using fragment manager ?
My regards
code
